# How to use json_decode to extract an inner information

Tags: php, json

I am new to php. I need some quick help with json_decode/php. I need to get values of g91 in an array, how can I do this? I suppose there is some recursion value that we can pass to json_decode...

```
{
    "e": "none",
    "f": "test",
    "g": [
        {
            "g1": "text2",
            "g9": {
                "text3": {
                    "g91": 0,
                    "g92": [
                        "text5"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "g1": "text1",          
            "g9": {
                "text4": {
                    "g91": 0,
                    "g92": [
                        "text6",
                        "text7"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that text3 is not fixed..in next record, I have text4..

Thanks!

Comment: Dup of [Get information from JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879472/), [Get “score” from JSON array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447084/)

Answer (score 5):

Pass `TRUE` to json_decode as second parameter

```
$output = json_decode($input,TRUE);
```

Than traverse the arrays. It should be something like

```
$output['g'][0]['g9']['text3']['g91']
```

Refer to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: but text3 is not fixed..so while referencing in a loop, what value will go here?

Comment: This gives error PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in .... in the line number where I try to reference output like this..

Answer (score 0):

After decode you will get an PHP array, just go to desired index:

```
$myJson['g'][0]['g9']['text3']['g91'];
```

But you can make some recursive loop to find all the results you search in that array.

Take a look in array docs from PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{
    "e": "none",
    "f": "test",
    "g": [
        {
            "g1": "text2",
            "g9": {
                "text3": {
                    "g91": 0,
                    "g92": [
                        "text5"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "g1": "text1",          
            "g9": {
                "text4": {
                    "g91": 0,
                    "g92": [
                        "text6",
                        "text7"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}';
$result = json_decode($json);
var_dump(array_merge($result->g[0]->g9->text3->g91, $result->g[1]->g9->text3->g91));
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the JSON for the testing purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json ={
        "e": "none",
        "f": "test",
        "g": [
            {
                "g1": "text2",
                "g9": {
                    "text3": {
                        "g91": 83,
                        "g92": [
                            "text5"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "g1": "text1",          
                "g9": {
                    "text4": {
                        "g91": 12,
                        "g92": [
                            "text6",
                            "text7"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    var arr=json["g"];
    for(key in arr){
       var obj=arr[key]["g9"];
       for(tex in obj)
       {
       alert(obj[tex]["g91"]);
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When I run it as "php file.php", I just get the dump of this file itself..(file.php contains the above code)