# Send JSON data to PHP and use it

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have an issue with sending json data with ajax to a php file and then use it to upload to the server.

If I'm making echo of the variable `$email_info->Name` the returned data value is empty.
I've tried json_decode but it doesn't do it.

This is the code I have,

Jquery:

```
$( document ).on('click', '#send_touch', function(){

    new_email = [];

    new_email.push({
    Name: $('#name').val(),
    Phone: $('#phone').val(),
    Email: $('#email').val(),
    Interested_in: $('#interested_in').val(),
    User_id: $('#email_user_id').val()
    });

    new_email = JSON.stringify({Email: new_email}, null, "\t");

        $.ajax({
            url: "core.php",
            type: "post",
            data: { NewMail: new_email
                  },
            success: function(data){  
                alert(data)          
            },
            error: function(){
            }   
     });    

});
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['NewMail']) {

 $timeStamp = time();

 $new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail'], true);

 $email_info = $new_email->Email[0];

 // New Email
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $dbPrefix . "touches (date, user_id, name, phone, email, interested_in, seen, status) VALUES ('".safeSQL($timeStamp)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->User_id)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Name)."','".safeSQL($email_info->Phone)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Email)."', '".safeSQL($email_info->Interested_in)."', '0', '1')") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());

 echo $email_info->Name;

}
```

If I make an echo on the PHP side for `$_POST['NewMail']` I get returned this:

```
{
\"Email\": [
    {
        \"Name\": \"John Doe\",
        \"Phone\": \"1234567\",
        \"Email\": \"john@doe.com\",
        \"Interested_in\": \"Text here..\",
        \"User_id\": \"1\"
    }
]
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql`. It is outdated. Move to `PDO` or `mysqli` which means "mysql improved". That should tell you it's better. I prefer PDO. I don't know what you "safeSQL" is, but scratch that and use prepared statements instead. Prepared statements guarantee your queries can't be attacked via sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this part in PHP :

```
$new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail'], true);
```

by this :

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['NewMail'] = stripslashes($_POST['NewMail']);
}
$new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail'], true);
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: NOTE!!! magic quotes ought to be off anyway!! If magic quotes are on, this is not really the solution! See http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. Magic quotes are totally removed in php 5.4

Comment: I think his problem is that (magic quotes) are turned on, Check out what he got after echo'ing $_POST['NewMail'].

Comment: Right, then the solution is to turn them off, not write code to deal with them.

Comment: I am not stick at leaving magic quotes = on , but there is no effective way to turn it off in the script. He can only turn it off through php.ini only if he have access to this config file.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me to get to my answer. Just realized that I have magic quotes turned 'on' on my server.

Comment: @Kim You are welcome. well, you own a server, keep in mind also that using "get_magic_quotes_gpc()" you can handle this for old versions of php if you don't have access to php.ini. Anyway, I'm glad your problem is solved. :)

Comment: And yes I'm planning to turn magic_quotes 'off'. But there are many many sites that will be affecting with changes on the server. But if I turn it off, could it break some code that are there in general on the server? (Maybe a dumb question)

Comment: @Hossam Yeah, I'm glad it's solved aswell :) Now I can keep on developing again! (Yihoo)

Comment: Probably, yes, depending on the other codes used in the server. But it is better to turn it off anyway as @m59 recommends, then check if there are new problems appeared. It will usually affect any php code handling user values entered in forms.

Answer (score 1):

I had magic_quotes turned 'on' on my server.

I realized it when testing Hossams code:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['NewMail'] = stripslashes($_POST['NewMail']);
}
```

So finally this got to work with this code:

```
if ($_POST['NewMail']) {

$timeStamp = time();

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST['NewMail'] = stripslashes($_POST['NewMail']);
}

$new_email = json_decode($_POST['NewMail'], true);

$email_info = $new_email['Email'][0];

// New Email
mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $dbPrefix . "touches (date, user_id, name, phone, email, interested_in, seen, status) VALUES ('".safeSQL($timeStamp)."', '".safeSQL($email_info['User_id'])."', '".safeSQL($email_info['Name'])."','".safeSQL($email_info['Phone'])."', '".safeSQL($email_info['Email'])."', '".safeSQL($email_info['Interested_in'])."', '0', '1')") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());

var_dump($email_info['Name']);

}
```

And I got the array with `$email_info['Name']` instead of `$email_info->Name`

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify to jquery that your sending data is a JSON type. Please configure the type of data in the ajax options. For example:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "core.php",
       type: "json", //here comes the data's type
       data: { NewMail: new_email
       },
       success: function(data){  
        alert(data)},
        error: function(){
        }`
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to specify that, but jQuery shouldn't be having trouble determining the data type automatically. I believe it because he used `stringify` rather than sending the object normally. Actually, I feel pretty sure setting it as json and then sending a string (like he is doing) will be bad.

Comment: Check this out please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926805/how-to-use-json-decode-to-extract-an-inner-information